# Angular app on IIS 8.x virtual directory has strange URL behavior

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs, iis

I'm having a problem with Angular JS on IIS 8.x with MVC. My application index page with virtual directory is like so:

```
https://myapp.xyz/VirtualDirectory/
```

That page loads the angular app. My angular routes are set up as:

```
$routeProvider
.when('/', {
    templateUrl: 'Content/Partials/Home/Index.html'
})
.when('/Error', {
    templateUrl: 'Content/Partials/Shared/Error.html'
})
.otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/Error'
});
```

So, if I access the first link, my URL looks like:

```
https://myapp.xyz/VirtualDirectory/#/
```

This works perfectly and resolves my partials fine. Angular requests the partials with the virtual directory in it so I see an HTTP request to:

```
https://myapp.xyz/VirtualDirectory/Content/Partials/Home/Index.html
```

However, if I access without a trailing slash like:

```
https://myapp.xyz/VirtualDirectory
```

Angular routes to:

```
https://myapp.xyz/VirtualDirectory#/
```

Once this happens, none of my routes work (they do not respect the virtual directory). They route as:

```
https://myapp.xyz/Content/Partials/Home/Index.html
```

This breaks all of my routes and templates defined in my directives. Any suggestions on how to fix this issue?

Comment: How do you have your routes defined?

Comment: I'll edit my template URL to show a full route example.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

try to add this in you head tag.

```
<html>
<head>
    <base href="/VirtualDirectory/">
</head>
<body>
    ...
</body>
```

Comment: This doesn't change anything.

Comment: I lied, this fixed the problem. However, I used: `<base href="@Url.Content("~")" />`

Comment: To further add, I actually had to use `<base href="@Url.Content("~/")" />` in order to get the correct base URL.

Answer (score 1):

I found that if you use the ./ syntax for the path, you don't need to involve Razor.

Code which fails:

```
$routeProvider.when("/productList", {
            templateUrl: "/app/products/productListView.html", controller: "ProductListController as vm"
        });
```

Code that works: (note the . before /app)

```
$routeProvider.when("/productList", {
            templateUrl: "./app/products/productListView.html", controller: "ProductListController as vm"
        });
```